# Is there a way to select a specific Character Reference for Jamo Letters (in Hangul/Korean writing) without using span

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to color code Hangul(Korean Language characters.) Each 'block' creates a syllable in Korean. Hangul is broken down into Jamo(similar to letters in English.)  When you type the jamo/letters in Korean they often combine to create one syllable and the computer often treats that as one block.  I want to be able to select a specific character reference among a list of character references that make up the syllables without using span.  When I use span the character reference gets separated from the combined block.  All I want to do it to know how I can select and color a specific character reference without separating it into a different block.

I have almost succeeded in what I want to do, but it requires using position:absolute; margin and z-index to make elements overlap to create the illusion of 1 block.  But it doesn't nicely style the jamo to make it look uniform with the rest of the normal text.  Also, I'm thinking there still might be a better way.

Character reference chart http://gernot-katzers-spice-pages.com/var/korean_hangul_unicode.html Below is an example of a list of mixed character references and regularly typed hangul.  I can add spaces if I want to add space.  When written like this, the hangul forms naturally into it's blocks due to using the chart from the link above.  How can I select for example the ㅂ letter(ᆸ)

```
&#x11B8;
```

(last one in the list before 니다) and change it's color and not sperate it into it's own block?

```
<p>&#x1100;&#x1161;&#x11B7;&#x1109;&#x1161; &#x1112;&#x1161;&#x11B8;니다</p>
```

On display, it will look like this
감사 합니다

The way I can kind of make it work is with this code.

```
  <style>
    .element { font-size:16px; position:absolute; }
    #element-1 { color:red; z-index:1; }
    #element-2 { color:red; margin:0px 0 0 3px; z-index:2; }
    #element-3 { color:green; margin:0px 0 0 0px; z-index:3; }
  </style>
<body>
  <div>
    <p><span style="color:red;">네, </span>
       <span id="element-1" class="element">&#x1100;</span>
       <span id="element-2" class="element">&#x1161;</span>
       <span id="element-3" class="element">&#x11B7;</span>
       <span style="color:green; margin-left: 19px;">사합니다</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Which should display
네, 감시합니다
But the 감 doesn't look matched in style because I did span for each letter of 감 which puts each jamo in a relative part of each block and then used techniques to overlap them using z-index, margin and absolute position. The font-style when used as a seperate block is not the same when it combines naturally.

I think the easiest way to do things is if I can figure out how to select character references and change the color in CSS without creating a separate block.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's impossible with pure html/css.

As you know, Korean(Hangeul) jamos have different shape on diffent syllables. For example, ㄱ  of 감 and ㄱ of 곤  has same code(x1100) but diffent shapes(the former is long at left, the latter is wide at top). There are 10 or more shapes for ㄱ(x1100) and the number of shapes are defined by font.

To fullfill your requirement,
You need to draw the jamo on canvas(or svg).
It's not easy but also not practical.

Nonetheless you want to challenge, see https://github.com/hatemogi/hallatype/blob/master/README.md

gg
gl